# Responsive верстка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, responsive

Всем привет! Мне очень редко приходилось заниматься версткой и конкретно CSS, но возникла необходимость сверстать несколько мокапов да и для себя уже хотелось бы наконец-то начать становиться более уверенным верстальщиком, тк занимаюсь веб-разработкой, но верстка пока мое слабое место. Значит, вопрос в следуещем: нужно сверстать несколько страниц и размеры отступов и шрифтов нужно брать с мокапа, но нужно, чтобы хорошо выглядело на разных разрешениях. В связи с этим возникает вопрос, как обычно поступают в таком случае? Переводят пиксели в относительные единицы vh, vw, % ? или есть какие-то другие способы.Знаю, что есть медиа квери, но для этого нужно писать дополнительный код и это увеличивает время разработки - такой вариант на данный момент не подходит. Может кто-нибудь из опытных верстальщиков или фронтенд девелоперов может пояснить, как здесь лучше поступить и как обычно делают? Если верстать в относительных единицах, то я читал, что размеры будут считаться относительно родительского блока, только не смог нагуглить относительно чего конкретно, относительно высоты родительского блока или ширины. Заранее всем спасибо за комментарии. Всем добра :)

Comment: Как именно должно выглядеть на разных разрешениях, рисует дизайнер. А уже в зависимости от того, что он нарисует, и решается, что нужно использовать в данном конкретном случае. Ничто не мешает сделать хорошо и на пикселях, если дизайн позволяет

Comment: «относительно высоты родительского блока или ширины» — очевидно, ширина — относительно ширины, высота — относительно высоты

Comment: а margin-top и margin-left - относительно высоты и ширины соответсвтенно?

Comment: А вот для margin/padding-top/bottom как раз единственное (вроде) исключение, что они считаются относительно ширины. Другие свойства вроде height или top считаются по-нормальному относительно высоты, но они требуют явно прописанного height для родительского блока